# Postgresql: alternative to WHERE IN respective WHERE NOT IN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several statements which access very large Postgresql tables i.e. with:

```
SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE a.id IN ( SELECT b.id FROM b );
SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE a.id NOT IN ( SELECT b.id FROM b );
```

Some of them even access even more tables in that way. What is the best approach to increase the performence, should I switch i.e. to joins?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JOIN will be far more efficient, or you can use EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.id FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.id = a.id)
```

The subquery will return at most 1 row.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to filter rows with an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT     a.id 
FROM       a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

Note that each version can perform differently; sometimes IN is faster, sometimes EXISTS, and sometimes the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i would recomend going to joins. It will speed up the select statements.