# Faster/efficient alternative to IN clause in custom/native queries in spring data jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-data, database-performance, openjpa, query-performance

I have a custom query along these lines. I get the list of orderIds from outside. I have the entire order object list with me, so I can change the query in any way, if needed.

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p INNER JOIN p.orders o WHERE o.orderId in :orderIds)")
public List<Person> findByOrderIds(@Param("orderIds") List<String> orderIds);
```

This query works fine, but sometimes it may have anywhere between 50-1000 entries in the orderIds list sent from outside function. So it becomes very slow, taking as much as 5-6 seconds which is not fast enough. My question is, is there a better, faster way to do this? When I googled, and on this site, I see we can use ANY, EXISTS: [Postgresql: alternative to WHERE IN respective WHERE NOT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769366/postgresql-alternative-to-where-in-respective-where-not-in) or create a temporary table: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/ways-to-speed-up-in-queries-under-postgresql or join this to VALUES clause: [Alternative when IN clause is inputed A LOT of values (postgreSQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053186/alternative-when-in-clause-is-inputed-a-lot-of-values-postgresql). All these answers are tailored towards direct SQL calls, nothing based on JPA. ANY keyword is not supported by spring-data. Not sure about creating temporary tables in custom queries. I think I can do it with native queries, but have not tried it. I am using spring-data + OpenJPA + PostgresSQL.

Can you please suggest a solution or give pointers? I apologize if I missed anything.

thanks,

Alice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WHERE EXISTS instead of IN Clause in a native SQL Query as well as in HQL in  JPA which results in a lot of performance benefits. Please see sample below

**Sample JPA Query:**

**SELECT emp FROM Employee emp JOIN emp.projects p where NOT EXISTS (SELECT project from Project project where p = project AND project.status <> 'Active')**